# Posição de componentes com bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma dúvida bem simples, não consigo posicionar elementos na horizontal com Bootstrap, como ficaria o código HTML com Bootstrap, igual dessa imagem?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vejam que tem o `label`, e ao lado o `radioGroup`, e abaixo outro `radiobutton` e ao lado `textbox` e `label` novamente, como ficaria exatamente esse código?
Sempre fica tudo abaixo do outro quando coloco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <form class="form-inline" role="form"  method="POST">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-2">Ends:</div>

                <input type="radio" name="group1" id="group1" class="radio" value="Never"> Never

            </div>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>

                <input type="radio" name="group1" id="group1" class="radio" value="After"> After
                <input type="text" name="texto2" id="texto2">
                occurrences

            </div>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>

                <input type="radio" name="group1" id="group1" class="radio" value="On"> On
                <input type="text" name="texto2" id="texto2">

            </div>

        </form>
```

Você pode fazer como no código acima e acrescentar uma div com a `class="row"` para cada linha que deseja criar um form com a `class="form-inline"` que faz com que todos os elementos fiquem em uma só linha.